# tick checkbox programmatically

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
$('#comment-form-subscribe input:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop("checked", true);
```

If checkboxes are unchecked, manually check them, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Do you execute this on document ready? What is `#comment-form-subscribe`? If it is an ancestor of the checkboxes, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have a selector issue: I'd check that the length of the jQuery object returned isn't 0. This is what I typically use:

EDIT: as @nbrooks pointed out, `:input` is deprecated. This might work:

```
$('#comment-form-subscribe').find('[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: The [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) is deprecated, and the rest is functionally identical.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#comment-form-subscribe input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('checked', true);
```